# transitions for widget attributes in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I just wanted to ask, is it possible to set transitions for attributes changes in kivy? Let's say my widget with id toolbar has opacity 0:

```
self.root.ids.toolbar.opacity = 0
```

Is it possible to set a transition if I plan to change it into opacity 1?

```
self.root.ids.toolbar.opacity = 1
```

Answers, suggestions, and corrections are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used kivy for some time and ran into similar problem, but I'm not an expert! So there might be better ways to do this.

That being said, here's a small example introducing fading effect. I believe, you should be able to implement a version for your own problem based on this.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<Screen1>:
    test_widget : ID1
    BoxLayout:
        padding : (50, 50)
        Button:
            text: 'Trigger'
            on_release:
                root.trigger()
        Label:
            id : ID1
            text: "Your Fading Text"
            font_size : 30
            bold : True
""")

class Screen1(Screen):
    # Loading object properties based on the id
    test_widget = ObjectProperty()

    # Variables for the fading effect
    event = None
    trans_type = "fade_out"

    # The trigger function schedules a task using Clock
    def trigger(self):
        if self.event != None:
            # See below
            self.event.cancel()
        # The clock calls the given function every X seconds
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda _:self.transition(self.test_widget), 0.03)

    def transition(self, widget):
        # Changing the opacity of the widget, pretty self explanatory I think
        if self.trans_type == "fade_out":
            if (widget.opacity > 0.5):
                widget.opacity -= 0.05
            else:
                self.trans_type = "fade_in"
                # We need to make sure to cancel events, otherwise they would not stop
                self.event.cancel()

        elif self.trans_type == "fade_in":
            if (widget.opacity < 1):
                widget.opacity += 0.05
            else:
                self.trans_type = "fade_out"
                self.event.cancel()

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # Creating a simple screen using ScreenManager and Screen
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Starting the app
    TestApp().run()
```

Also, you might be interested in:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.animation.html

This might simplify your solution, however I'm not familiar with it, so you have to figure that out for yourself :)